# Addition in Field.

Tags: field-theory

Find counterexamples to the following statements:

> In every field $\Bbb F$, if $a\in \Bbb F$, $a+a=0$, then $a=0$;

Counterexample: Consider $\Bbb Z_2$.  Let $a = 1$, so $a + a = 2 = 0 \mod 2$. but $a \ne 0$.

> In every field $\Bbb F$, $a^2+1 \neq 0 $ for all $a \in \Bbb F $

Counterexample: Consider $\Bbb Z_2$.  Let $a = 1$, so $a^2 + 1 = 2 = 0 \mod 2$. Hence $a^2 + 1 = 0 $.

> In every field $\Bbb F$, $−1\neq 1$

Counter example: Consider $\Bbb Z_2$. Then $-1 = 1 \mod 2$, and $1 = 1 \mod 2$. Hence $-1 = 1$.

Please improve my answers and thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your second counterexample is incorrect, unless you meant $a^2+1 = 0$ in the problem statement.

Comment: so what would be answer for second one? I am showing $a^2 + 1 = 0 $. Your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fields have no non-zero divisors. Your second question is equivalent to asking when $a^2 = 0$. What does this say about $a$ - if it exists at all?

Comment: Ok, then let a = 0, then $a^2 + 1$ = 1 = 1 mod 2? Any hints @bof Thanks in advance tho!

Comment: In any field, $0^2+1=1$. Are you sure that's really the second question?

Answer (score 0):

For both $(1)$ and $(3)$ the only counterexamples are fields of characteristic $2$ (e.g. $\mathbb F_2$, $\mathbb F_{2^m}$, $\mathbb F_2(x)$ with $x$ trascendental, etc.. ).

For $(2)$ you can take every field that contains the $4$-th primitive roots of unity. For example $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb Q(i) $, $\mathbb F_{p^{2s}}$ where $p$ is a prime, etc

Comment: So for (2), Suppose $a^2 + 1 = 0$ for all $a \in F$, then $a^2 = i $, then $ a^2 + 1 = i + 1 = 0 $. Hence $ a^2 + 1 = 0 $. Such counter example exists in the complex field. What would you say about my answer for (2). Your inputs are much appreciated!

Comment: Wait a moment. For a counterexample in (2) you have to find a field in which there exists an element $a \in \mathbb F$ such that $a^2+1=0$ (not for all $a\in \mathbb F$). It means that $a^2=-1$, so we need that in $\mathbb F$ there is an element $a$ that is a solution of the equation $x^2=-1$. The examples that I wrote in the answer have this property.